# Can I send three requests per time to my server using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**The problem:**
I'm uploading images via JavaScript to a asp.net server page. To compute the progressive operation for each image uploading, I designed that **each image has an independent request**. But I'm afraid this may overload the server, specially if the number of requests is big.

**The idea:**
Rather than sending all requests asynchronously I want to send them as packets of three.
After those three are sent and all other requests have to wait until those three finished.

**The Question:**

> How i can make the the other requests to wait until the previous ones
>   finish?

**The code:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputFiles.files.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {                
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open('POST', 'Ajax.ashx');
        request.setRequestHeader('Cashe-Control', 'no-cashe');

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file[]', inputFiles.files[i]);

        request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (event) {//happening
            if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var percent = parseFloat(event.loaded) / parseFloat(event.total), 
                    progressWidth = percent * parseFloat(progressBarWidth);
                progressBar.children().css('width', progressWidth + 'px');
            } else {}
        });
        request.upload.addEventListener('load', function (event) {});
        request.upload.addEventListener('error', function (event) {});
        request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function (event) {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    var code = eval(this.response);
                } else {}
            }
        });
        request.send(data);
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've added the `jQuery` tag, you could:

- create `n` [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) requests
- wait with the help of [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when) until all of them resolved
- and then send the next `n` requests

Something like this:

```
function uploadImages(images) {
    var requests = [];

    // upload 3 images (or less, if there are less images in the array)
    for (var i = 0, len = Math.min(3, images.length); i < len; i++) {
        var image = images.pop(),
            formData = new FormData(),
            request, formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file[]', image);

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "Ajax.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                // add progress stuff
                // http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/
            },
            success: function (data) { }
        });

        requests.push(request);
    }

    // when all our requests have finished and there are images left, start the next round...
    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {
        if (images.length) {
            uploadImages(images);
        }
    });
}
```

[Simplified Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6fv7fheb/1/)

Comment: Thank Andreas for your answer, i do not try your code yet but i wonder if 
 requests=[] has any thing useful, in other words what is this.

Comment: The array is used in the loop to store the created requests (`requests.push(request);`) which are then passed all at once to `$.when()` with the help of [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (`$.when.apply($, requests)`)

Comment: Dear Andreas, i analyzed your code and it convinced me but when i used it, the block of $.when.apply($, requests).done(function () {} does not work  i added some tags and alert functions to do anything but nothing was showed.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle I've created?

Comment: Brother Andreas, you can take a quick look to code that i posted with Answer 2

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
i was using jquery **1.4 version** so it did not work.
Now i'm working on **1.11 version** and all done well.

**$.when.apply() just work with jQuery 1.5 or later.**